# How to install weather indicator on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: python, dependencies

I tried to install it from the market but that's what it says
[image]

Comment: have you tried with `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in Terminal. It is called "My Weather Indicator"

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```